# What is the SMPP protocol?

Tags: protocols, smpp

What is the SMPP protocol and how does it work?

I've not even seen it yet and have to start with introduction onward.

Comment: You show NO effort on your side. What have you searched already? What don't you understand?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Peer-to-Peer

Comment: @Jeames I was going to tell Venil to google for that himself… After all, it's only the top hit…

Comment: Thanking you both. My searching is under progress.

Comment: @DonalFellows I should have linked this one: http://bit.ly/HQ9Jid ;)

Comment: The primary use of SMPP is to send and receive medium-to-high volumes of SMS texts.

Answer (score 25):

**SMPP is a low-level binary Internet protocol.**

The primary use of SMPP is to send and receive medium-to-high volumes of SMS texts.

SMPP uses a standard Internet connection to connect to an SMPP provider, to do away with or compliment the purchase of a GSM modem or a SIM card.

SMPP offers the following benefits over a GSM modem:

- Send by a meaningful name e.g. a company name instead of phone number.
- Send by a short codes; 3, 4, or 5 digit phone number instead of the normal length.
- Faster processing

Software:

- [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/) is an open-source client for experimenting on.
- ActiveXperts [Mobile Messaging Toolkit](http://www.activexperts.com/mobile-messaging-component/) is a commercial solution with SMPP simulator.

For the record: I'm a programmer at ActiveXperts, actively involved in SMPP and SMS related developments.

Answer (score 4):

Fundamentally it's the main protocol that SMS aggregator companies
(mostly!) use when communicating with different type of Gateways (GW).

Please check these links...they will definitely help you out understand SMPP more thoroughly.
http://www.simpleteam.com/downloads/SMPP_v3_4_Issue1_2.pdf

http://www.ehow.com/facts_7344160_smpp-protocol_.html

**Wikipedia definition:**
"SMPP is a telecommunications industry protocol for exchanging SMS messages between SMS peer entities such as short message service centers and/or External Short Messaging Entities. It is often used to allow third parties (e.g. value-added service providers like news organizations) to submit messages, often in bulk."